# Backbone fetch, anywhere to make it shorten?

Tags: backbone.js

```
 renderControl: function () {
        var that = this;
        var _CountryCol = new CountryCol();
        var _ComboCol = new ComboCol();

        _CountryCol.fetch({
            success: function (data) {
                that.$("#ctr").select2({
                    placeholder: "Select a Country",
                    allowClear: true,
                    data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)),
                });
            }
        });
        _ComboCol.fetch({
            data: { id: 'status' },
            success: function (data) {
                that.$("#sta").select2({
                    placeholder: "Select a status",
                    allowClear: true,
                    data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)),
                });
            }
        });
        _ComboCol.fetch({
            data: { id: 'marital' },
            success: function (data) {
                that.$("#mrt").select2({
                    placeholder: "Select a marital",
                    allowClear: true,
                    data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)),
                });
            }
        });
        _ComboCol.fetch({
            data: { id: 'daytype' },
            success: function (data) {
                that.$("#dty").select2({
                    placeholder: "Select a type",
                    allowClear: true,
                    data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)),
                });
            }
        });
        this.$("#hpn, #hmn, #icn").numeric({ decimal: false, negative: false });
        this.$('#dob').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
        });
    },
```

Anywhere to make it shorten? The code work fine, just by calling multiple ajax look troublesome and tedious, the code look less elegant also, if there is anyone have better idea on it, can share the way of to code in backbone so that it will be easier to manage, thanks

**Update 1:**

I had further reduce the code a little bit more, by referring to Marc idea, but not sure if this is the correct way, any feedback will be great

```
       renderControl: function () { //use to render special control
            var that = this;
            var _CountryCol = new CountryCol();
            var _ComboCol = new ComboCol();
            $.when(
                _CountryCol.fetch(),
                _ComboCol.fetch({ data: { id: 'status' } }),
                _ComboCol.fetch({ data: { id: 'marital' } }),
                _ComboCol.fetch({ data: { id: 'daytype' } })).done(
                function (country, status, marital, daytype) {
                    that.populateSelect('#ctr', "Select a country", country);
                    that.populateSelect("#sta", "Select a status", status);
                    that.populateSelect("#mrt", "Select a marital", marital);
                    that.populateSelect("#dty", "Select a type", daytype); 
            });

            this.$("#hpn, #hmn, #icn").numeric({ decimal: false, negative: false });
            this.$('#dob').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
            });
        },
        populateSelect: function (selector, placeholder, collection) {
            debugger;
            this.$(selector).select2({
                placeholder: placeholder,
                allowClear: true,
                data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(collection[0]))
            });
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS @mike said, use a listener.

To do this you'll want to add the code before the fetch like to:

```
_CountryCol.on('sync', function(collection) {
  that.$("#ctr").select2({
    placeholder: "Select a Country",
    allowClear: true,
    data: JSON.stringify(collection.toJSON())
  });
});
_CountryCol.fetch()
```

Though this solution just moves the code from one place to another, and doesn't really cut the code down any. Putting the duplicated code in a function will though:

```
populateSelect = function(selector, placeholder, collection) {
  that.$(selector).select2({
    placeholder: placeholder,
    allowClear: true,
    data: JSON.stringify(collection.toJSON())
  });
}

_CountryCol.on('sync', function(collection) {
  populateSelect("#ctr", "Select a Country", collection);
});
_CountryCol.fetch();

_ComboCol.on('sync', function(collection) {
  populateSelect("#sta", "Select a status", collection)
});
_ComboCol.fetch({data: {id: 'status'}});
```

Comment: you did cut down the code, by reduce the select2 content, at least it look more elegent than my code right now

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the overall picture here but usually in Backbone it's preferable to handle responses to fetches with listeners on the collection, not callbacks on the `fetch` method itself. This way you'll probably only have to to write your callback code once.

Comment: Any sample can I refer to?

Comment: @Se0ng11 Backbone's doc: http://backbonejs.org/#Events. Also, you should make a collection of `ComboCol` so that you only have to fetch once, and views that have your selectors (`#sta`, `#mrt`...) as elements and that will listen some of their model's events.